# Setting object to nil iOS7 vs iOS8

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

WI have an iPad kiosk app that displays videos on an external monitor connected to the iPad via HDMI. I have a viewController that manages the view on the external monitor. When I am done playing back a video I nil out the MPMoviePlayerController instance. In iOS7 this works fine, but in iOS8 I get a hard crash after setting the moviePlayer to nil.

```
- (void)removeMoviePlayer {
[self.moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self removeMovieNotificationHandlers];
self.moviePlayerController = nil;}
```

With Zombies enabled I get a message in the debugger:

```
[MPAVController release]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

Again, this crash does not happen when the app runs under iOS7. What has changed that is causing this crash?

Comment: What does `self removeMovieNotificationHandlers` do?

Comment: It'd be kinda nice if you added the line the crash happens on. (Exception breakpoint)

Comment: There's not necessarily a change that someone can point to — much more likely you've some tiny obscure misuse somewhere that technically means your app has undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour under 7 needn't correlate with undefined behaviour under 8. Question one: are you using ARC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple days of trial and error I discovered that when trying to nil out the MPMoviePlayerController instance when the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackState was MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused, the app would crash. When a video reaches the end, the MPMoviePlayerController sends a MPMoviePlaybackDidFinish notification that reports the playback state as MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused. The fix was to test for playback state and if paused call [MPMoviePlayerController stop]. That changes the MPMoviePlaybackState to MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped, and you can then nil out the instance without a crash.

This crash did not happen before iOS 8. Code below:

```
-(void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self stopVideo:notification];
}

- (void)stopVideo:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (self.moviePlayerController) {
        if (self.moviePlayerController.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying || self.moviePlayerController.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused) {
            [self.moviePlayerController stop];
        }
        [self cleanUpVideo];
    }
}

- (void)cleanUpVideo {
    [self killProgressTimer];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        self.closedCaptionLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
        self.moviePlayerController.view.alpha = 0.0f;
        self.backgroundImageView.alpha = 1.0f;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self removeMoviePlayer];
        [self resetClosedCaptions];
        [self.delegate videoDidStop];
    }];
}

- (void)removeMoviePlayer {
    [self.moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self removeMovieNotificationHandlers];
    self.moviePlayerController = nil;

}
```